# What is the difference between these two differetly-priced Tamron 28-75mm lenses?

Tags: lens, tamron

I'am getting ready to buy some lenses for basketball and am having trouble finding the difference between these two lenses seeing as one is $390 and the other is $500.

1) - $390 - [Tamron AF 28-75mm f/2.8 XR Di LD Aspherical (IF) Autofocus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00V7BIIE6)

2) - $500 - [Tamron AF 28-75mm f/2.8 SP XR Di LD Aspherical (IF)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001955P8W)

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. They are the same lens. You can't go by the photos and since Tamron currently only makes one version of this lens, it has to be the same.

The version without the AF motor in the body is the A09N.

Th version with the AF motor in the body is the A09NII.

Tamron began making the 28-75mm with the AF motor in the body in 2008. All current Tamron lenses have the AF motor in the body except the 180mm. I don't know when they stopped making the older A09N version, but I suspect it was also way back in 2008

[Tamron Compatibility Chart](http://www.tamron-usa.com/lenses/prod/assets/pdfs/slr_compatability_chart.pdf)

Comment: If you go down the listing to check the model number ( it's way down there :-) ), they are the same model number, and those are the Tamron model numbers, not Amazon ones.

Answer (score 1):

The current Tamron Lenses have the AF motor built into the Lens.

Out of the two models you link, you will notice that the $500 model lists as one with a built in AF motor and I believe that is what makes it different.

A few years ago, Nikon decided to no longer have the AF motor built into all their cameras and instead, to incorporate it into the lens itself.
This also meant that independent lens manufacturers such as Tamron and Sigma had to produce their Nikon lenses with the AF motor built in.

Today, Nikon DSLR’s that do not have a in-built AF motor are; D40, D60, D3000 Series and the D5000 Series. They will therefore require a lens that has the AF motor.

Nikon DSLR’s that still have the AF motor incorporated into the body are, D50/70/80/90/100, D200-300, D7000, D600/700/800 and the D1,D2,D3,D4 Pro models and related models D2H, D2X, D2Xs, D2Hs, D3X, D3S.

One other thing to notice, when Tamron changed their lens to incorporate the AF Motor, they never changed the actual part number and this in the UK lead to a lot of confusion until the older non AF motor Model was taken off the shelves and officially discontinued

Hope this helps

Comment: While the descriptions make it unclear, Amazon clearly lists both as model number A09 II.

Comment: Your remark about Tamron not changing part number to reflect significant changes in different versions of the lens would explain a number of stories of confusion I have heard over the years.  Interesting.

Comment: @DanWolfgang - it is not uncommon for Amazon or their affiliates to populate the description from one feed and the part number from another. The more expensive Tamron Lens clearly describes the version II - AF09NII-700 Lens and the cost is competitive with other Resellers. Where as, the cheaper Lens describes the legacy Tamron AF09 and once again matches cost of those of other Resellers... It is confusing that Amazon lists both as AF09NII only, but this could also be the fault of Tamron as something similar happened in the UK

Comment: @DanWolfgang - However, saying that, I could be completely wrong and the cheaper version could actually be the A09NII-700 model, in which case, its a great deal. My only concern will then be, why is it being sold for so much less! is it a grey import?

Comment: @AbdulNQuraishi: yeah, I don't know what the difference is. I think the OP's answer is that he needs to contact the seller to verify model numbers and any differences like warranty. All we can tell him is what we can read.

Comment: What are the 1, 2, 3, 4DX models? Do you mean the D1 series (D1, D1H, D1X), D2 series (D2H, D2X, D2Xs, D2Hs), D3 series (D3, D3X, D3S), etc.?

Comment: @MichaelClark - thats what I meant - Have updated the answer using your descriptions